# Why is my NextJS PWA install prompt being automatically dismissed ins Android Chrome?

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps

I have a NextJS PWA that prompts the user to install with a banner with a simple clickable `<a>`. This entire flow works fine on Windows Chrome, but on Android Chrome, the banner shows but the native install prompt does not show and is automatically dismissed. In Android, I AM able to install the app successfully on Android via the three dots menu and the "Install App" menu item.

Relevant code:

`

```
 const [installPrompt, setInstallPrompt] = useState(null);
  const [displayMode, setDisplayMode] = useState(null);

  function getDisplayMode() {
    const isStandalone = window.matchMedia(
      "(display-mode: standalone)",
    ).matches;
    const navigatorStandalone =
      "standalone" in window.navigator && window.navigator["standalone"];
    if (document.referrer.startsWith("android-app://")) {
      return "twa";
    } else if (navigatorStandalone || isStandalone) {
      return "standalone";
    }
    return "browser";
  }
  function handleInstallPrompt(e:Event) {
    alert("installable!");
    e.preventDefault();
    setInstallPrompt(e);
  }
  async function handleInstallClick(e) {
    alert("clicked!");
    if (installPrompt) {
      alert("has install prompt");
      installPrompt.prompt();
      let choice = await installPrompt.userChoice;
      if (choice?.outcome === "accepted") {
        alert("accepted install");
        setInstallPrompt(null);
      }
      if (choice?.outcome === "dismissed") {
        alert("dismissed install");
        setInstallPrompt(null)
      }
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", handleInstallPrompt);
    setDisplayMode(getDisplayMode());


    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", handleInstallPrompt);
    };
    }, []);
```

...

`<a href="#" onClick={handleInstallClick}> Install me </a>`

I would expect that this install flow would work equally well in Android Chrome. The sequence of "alerts" that fire on Android are: "installable!", "clicked!", "has install prompt", "dismissed install"